# VPN Access Client implementation in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, vpn, openvpn

I have a requirement to implement VPN client implementation in iOS application. I have done some google, but not able to find the right content for me. Is there ant API available to implement VPN client in iOS Application? And how can we handle multiple connections, 1-key connect plugin, support for PPTP,L2TP,TCP/UDP, PSK Cisco IPSec,Open VPN. In goggling i found all the time CISCO AnyConnect application reference from Appstore.
Kindly guide me in best way. I will be highly oblidge.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no public VPN API in iOS SDK. You have to implement the protocols and everything on your own. But there are some -old- projects available regarding openvpn.

https://github.com/search?q=openvpn+iphone

Comment: Thanx nikos !! I will look into this code and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

on iOS 9+, you can use Network Extension's NETunnelProvider class to implement your custom vpn protocol.